# how to create mutual push key for two user in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Well I am working on a Chat app. I want to creat groups and direct messaging like Whatsapp. but how to create a mutual (same) key for two user? for example assume that I have 2 users which are user A and user B. If a create a mutual key for two user my data structure look like this:

- Firebase

  - Direct Messages

    - Mutual key for user A and user B

      - push key 1

        - id: user A
        - message: hello
      - push key 2

        - id: user B
        - message: thnks A, how are you?
      - push key 3
      - push key 4
      - ...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot push the same id for two different users. The `push()` method generates a unique id for a single user. All push Ids are generated entirely on the client side without consultation with the server or other devices. To solve this, is need to change the logic of structuring your database. Rather than that, i recomand you create a chat group in which users can subscribe. In this way, it don't need to create two same push ids you only need to create one, and the users will be apart of that chat group.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But, you can specify your own key when writing the data out. Maybe I’m missing something with the original question, but can’t you just sort the usernames in your group, concatenate, then hash and use that as your group key?

Comment: Who are you asking this?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase support "Send Messages to Topic", it may help you.
Create a group chat room, and use the group chat room name as a "topic" name.
When you send a messages to the users in the chat room, you may use the "topic" name.
Check below following url: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging